# How to make this code work in jQuery 1.4.x?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The on() method isn't supported in jQuery 1.4.x. Can someone tell me how to fix this so it's compatible?

```
$(document).on({
  mouseenter: MyObj.mouseenter,
  mouseleave: MyObj.mouseleave
}, '.class');
```

Comment: That is equivalent to `live`.

Comment: Upgrading jQuery isn't an option. Yeah, I know.

Comment: Do you really need `document` level event delegation? This is usually undesirable, especially for events like `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` where the events are constantly firing. This is why `.live()` was bad.

Comment: Do you understand the tools you're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the delegate method.

```
$(document).delegate('.class',{
  mouseenter: MyObj.mouseenter,
  mouseleave: MyObj.mouseleave
});
```

Note: jQuery 1.4.3+ required

Comment: Just wondering, is $(document).delegate() equivalent to live?

Comment: No, it is far more efficient.

Comment: @KevinB: It's no more efficient when applied to the `document`.

Comment: Other than the fact that it doesn't try to select all existing .class elements then do nothing with them. Though, in practice, yes they'll be about the same when using document.

Comment: @KevinB: Come on... that's a one-time DOM selection in the beginning. Yes it's wasted, but is trivial when compared to the overall picture.

Comment: @amnotiam to answer my own question

Comment: As far as the one time dom selection in the beginning, consider how much of a delay $(".row") can have if it was a class on every row of a table that had 100+ rows, that can definitely begin to impact performance in a noticeable way in some browsers.

Comment: @KevinB: Yes, especially in IE7 and lower *(no qSA)*, though if using `.live()`, there's no reason to wait for the DOM to be ready when setting up the handler. It should generally be done in the `head` without waiting. That way there's a very minimal DOM. Either way, it's good that jQuery finally had the sense to deprecate `.live()`. Too many people didn't understand it, and used it for everything.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `live` instead of `on` to make it compatible with old versions of jQuery. `live` always works for the elements that will be created after the page has been loaded.

jQuery 1.7 deprecated live() method and 1.9 has removed it. It has been replaced by `on`.

If you can however, it is wiser to just upgrade your jQuery.

Do not use `bind` because this offers not the same functionality as `live`.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply various listeners directly to a jQuery object like so:

```
$(".class").mouseover(function() {

}).mouseout(function() {

});
```

... or this:

```
$(".class").mouseenter(function() {

}).mouseleave(function() {

});
```

Example available here: http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: You are not using delegation here

Comment: The code example in the question is limited. The developer may not have required the use of `.on()` in the first place. Either way we're unable to tell currently.

Comment: @diggersworld he actually used delegation in his example.  as you can see he bound the handlers to the document and has `'.class'` as his selector

Comment: @wirey: agreed, however what's to say he didn't just copy the code from somewhere else without knowing what it does.